# WCF 'sub main' not found

Tags: vb.net, wcf, service, host

I must be losing my mind...

After getting a test WCF hosted in a windows service, I'm trying for another one (practice, practice, practice).

I created a WCF service library, added one function. Then created a Windows Service, and added my WCF to the project. Did the rest of the stuff located here (http://joefreeman.co.uk/blog/2010/03/creating-a-setup-project-for-a-windows-wcf-service-with-visual-studio/)

Now I'm getting this "Sub Mian was not found in [WCF app]" error when I try to build the solution.

I didn't think WCF projects required a Sub Main as they are services and not applications. What am I doing wrong? I didn't have a sub main in my last project. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WCF service itself doesn't need a Sub Main, but your Windows Service does.

Compare against your previously built, working Windows Service.

edit: using C#, when I create a new project using the Windows Service template, I get the following initial code in a `Program.cs` file (`static void Main` is your `Sub Main`). I'd be *very* surprised if you don't also have this in your Windows Service.

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    static void Main()
```

Comment: Can't find a difference between the two. Neither have a sub main, both have OnStart and OnStop with identical code (except for the WCF name). Blows my mind!

Comment: I use C#, but when I use the 'new Windows Service' template I get a `Program.cs` file.

Comment: What happened was I attempted to duplicate my former working model, except I used a regular WCF as opposed to the web WCF I had in the original model. Note to self: They are different! Fix was to simply copy the original, rename everything and edit the config files to match the new directories. Thanks, though, for your posts!

Answer (score 4):

For others who are looking for the same answer I was...

Created a service in VB.NET (VS2010), and was getting the same error listed above...

```
'Sub Main' was not found in 'SERVICENAME.Service1'.
```

In VB.NET, VS2010 created a "Service1.Designer.vb" file for me automatically. Inside of that file was:

```
    Shared Sub Main()
    Dim ServicesToRun() As System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase

    ' More than one NT Service may run within the same process. To add
    ' another service to this process, change the following line to
    ' create a second service object. For example,
    '
    '   ServicesToRun = New System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase () {New Service1, New MySecondUserService}
    '
    ServicesToRun = New System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase() {New SERVICENAME}

    System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun)
End Sub
```

To resolve this, right-click your solution name in the solution explorer, go to the "Application" tab, and pick "Sub Main" as your Startup object in the "Startup object" drop-down box. Recompile.

Granted, the file names and structure will be different in C#, but the idea is that Visual Studio put the Main procedure SOMEWHERE, and it hopefully should already know where it is.

Answer (score 0):

Check you haven't accidentally changed the Application type to something stupid like "windows forms app", hit the properties of the project and make sure it's on "class library".